# Mobile vs PC structure

Tags: html, css

I have a simple desktop website and I would like to redesign each page for mobile. 
To be clearer desktop and mobile versions will be different.

My idea was to do as follow :

```
<html>

<style>
#containermobile {
display:none;
}
@media (max-device-width: 769px) {

#containerPC{
display:none;
</style>

<div id="containerPC">
<body>
</body>
</div>

<div id="containermobile">
<body>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

The PC website is displaying properly. But the mobile website is showing a blank page.

What am I doing wrong ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

- There are multiple syntax errors in css
- You cannot have two body in html document

Probably you're looking for:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media (min-device-width: 770px) {
    #containermobile {display:none;}
}
@media (max-device-width: 769px) {
    #containerPC {display:none;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="containerPC">pc</div>
<div id="containermobile">mobile</div>

</body>

</html>
```